# @State willSet and didSet: depends on the way you change it

Tags: swiftui, state, observers

why are willSet and didSet called while directly sets the variable and are not called when you change variable with `+=` operator? The same problem with `.toggle()` for bool.

```
struct TestDidSet: View {
    @State var usingWillSet = false
    @State var text: String = ""{
        willSet{
            print("willSet")
        }
        didSet{
            print("didSet")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(text)
            Button(action: {
                self.usingWillSet.toggle()
            }){
                Text(usingWillSet ? "willSet is active" : "willSet is not active")
            }
            Button(action: {
                if self.usingWillSet{
                    let newValue = self.text
                    self.text = newValue + "a"
                }else{
                    self.text += "a"
                }
            }){
                Text("toggle from inside")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247370/toggle-function-on-bool-does-not-call-didset-is-this-a-bug) it is said that its a known bug, but in that [link](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12407) I see this bug is marked as RESOLVED, but I still have this problem in Xcode 11.4 (11E146). So should we wait for fix or its not a bug?

Comment: Have you tried Xcode 11.5?

Comment: you are right! In 11.5 it works correctly